# ng-change executing before ng-model is set for a <select>

Tags: javascript, select, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have the following html and js

```
 <select ng-change="setBillGroup()" ng-model="bill.groupId" class="span8" ng-options="d.id as d.name for d in groups"></select>
```

and the corresponding js is

```
   $scope.bill=[];
   $scope.setBillGroup = function() {
   var $groupId = $scope.bill.groupId; .... }
```

Here is the $scope.groups JSON

```
 $scope.groups= [
{id:'1',users:[1,2,3,4],name:'SLC '},
{id:'2',users:[1,2],name:'Denver'},
{id:'3',users:[2,3],name:'Ski Club'},
{id:'4',users:[2,5],name:'Family'},
{id:'5',users:[1,2,3,5],name:'whatever'}
];
```

I keep getting the following error everytime I select something from the select form tag elements.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'groupId' of null
at Object.$scope.setBillGroup
```

It appears that the ng-change function is running even fore the ng-model is set. Is there a way to make ng-change function setBillGroup() wait for the ng-model to be set after a user selects an item? I did check the value of the $scope.bill and the {{bill}} value is correctly set to {"groupId":"1"}

Thank you.

Comment: Does it give you an error, even if you initialize `$scope.bill` at top of your controller?

Comment: @toshshimayama  It's set to [] ($scope.bills=[];) so I'm hoping that the value will be set using ng-model before it is accessed in the setBillGroup() function. P.S I edited the question to post this info. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't get any errors while running your code. Take a look http://plnkr.co/edit/9BMsaLKv3QR0qI4V9OEg

Comment: @jaux thank you! It was something stupid I did. Seems like initialized $scope.bill to null instead of [] as I asked in the original question. I just checked the code again and found the typo. I'm so glad that programmers are able to help each other this way and grow in a positive way. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It was a typo mistake I made. Opposite to what I posted in the question $scope.bill was instead initialized to

$scope.bill =null;

so it was throwing the error. The error went away when I initialized it properly
     $scope.bill =[];

kudos to @jaux for helping me find the problem